# C# Convoyor-Belt-like buffer - Time constrained buffer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, buffer

I'd like to program a buffer that is time constrained. It means that I want to be able to continuously fill up a List of string (for instance) and every 2 secondes that list is added to another list (or send to the network) whether this list has 1 or more elements, but another List of string take its place so that there are always a List of string being filled up.

How can I do that in C# ?

Comment: You want to create a thread safe buffer, which is pushed at one end and popped at the other (aka a queue). Also when a certain condition is hit (e.g. the buffer is full/ a certain time has elapsed) you want to use a second instance of the buffer so that you can do something with the items in the first instance. I'm just trying to understand what you are asking!

Comment: You understood it right. That is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in C# by using a combination of

- the generic [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) collection class,
- a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) to execute a method at regular intervals in a worker thread, and
- a [*lock* statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to synchronize access to a resource shared by threads.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it didn't work. The clue was to execute my main thread outside the timer thread.